# Confusing plot point in The Sense of an Ending

Tags: plot-explanation, the-sense-of-an-ending

Probable spoilers ahead.

In [The Sense of an Ending](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4827986/) (2017), are we to understand that Sarah Ford (Emily Mortimer) slept with both Adrian and Tony? The film is told in flashbacks from an unreliable narrator, with more information being passed with each iteration, but I still cannot decide whether she slept with Tony.  All we ever saw was her subtle hand gesture as they were driving away.

> The second Adrian was credited as 'Adrian Junior,' which confirms that Sarah and Adrian were intimate. But were Sarah and Tony, as well?

Or was this left deliberately vague?

Comment: http://www.vox.com/culture/2017/3/10/14858426/sense-of-ending-review-jim-broadbent-charlotte-rampling Plus, this is based on a book: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sense_of_an_Ending

Comment: @BCdotWEB I'm not sure how that helps answer my question, unless you're suggesting I read the book to find out?